Ошибка при создании проекта на Ruby on Rails
An error occurred while installing psych (5.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  debug was resolved to 1.9.2, which depends on
    irb was resolved to 1.13.2, which depends on
      rdoc was resolved to 6.7.0, which depends on
        psych
         run  bundle lock --add-platform=x86_64-linux
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Writing lockfile to C:/Development/Web-Development/Ruby/My_Ruby_Project/servev/Gemfile.lock
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find irb-1.13.2 in locally installed gems
       rails  importmap:install
Could not find irb-1.13.2 in locally installed gems
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
Could not find irb-1.13.2 in locally installed gems
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
PS C:\Development\Web-Development\Ruby\My_Ruby_Project> gem install bundler
Fetching bundler-2.5.14.gem
Successfully installed bundler-2.5.14
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.5.14
Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.5.14
Done installing documentation for bundler after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
PS C:\Development\Web-Development\Ruby\My_Ruby_Project> cd .\servev\
PS C:\Development\Web-Development\Ruby\My_Ruby_Project\servev> gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-2.5.14
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.5.14
Done installing documentation for bundler after 0 seconds
1 gem installed


Ruby 3.3.2
Ruby on Rails 7.1.3.4
Операционная система Windows 11
